# Equivalence of Norms on Sobolev Space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I am looking at the Sobolev space

$W^s=\{ f \in L^2(\Omega): \partial^{\alpha}f \in L^2(\Omega) \ \forall \ |\alpha|\le s \} $

for some $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

How can one proof that the norms:

$$||f||=\sum_{|\alpha| \le s} ||\partial^{\alpha}f||_{L^2}$$

and

$$|||f|||=||\hat{f}(k)(1+|k|^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}||_{L^2}$$

are equivalent?

Here $\hat{f}$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$.

I know I can write $\|f\|=∑_{|α|≤s|}k^α\|\hat f\|_{L^2}.$ Then I think one can show that $\sum_{|\alpha| \le s} |k^{\alpha}\hat{f}| \le |(1+|k|^2)^{s/2}\hat{f}|,$ since the expansion of the brackets contains all the terms $|α|≤s.$

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: i know i can write $||f||=\sum_{|\alpha| \le s} ||k^{\alpha}\hat{f}||_{L^2}$. Then i think one can may show that $\sum_{|\alpha| \le s} |k^{\alpha}\hat{f}| \le |(1+|k|^2)^{s/2}\hat{f}|$. Since the expansion of the $(1+|k|^2)^{s/2}$ contains all the summands in $|\alpha| \le s$